# is using views faster or slower than just writing the whole sql from scratch

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have 3 tables (A,B,C) and I need quite often to query the result of

```
A inner join B
union
A inner join C
```

I'm just thinking which way is going to be faster:

- to write in each query the whole thing from scratch
- to create a view and use it in queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the view contains no aggregations, then using the view will be exactly the same as using the raw SQL.  No aggregations means that a where clause can be applied 'internally' to a view where the optimiser deems optimal (based on statistics). (I think this is often referred to as 'pushing' the where clause inside a view)

Answer (score 2):

A view in general is nothing else but a stored version of the SQL, in that case no. However you might get some benefit by using indexed view, especially with aggregations....having said that..indexed views have a ton of restrictions...for one `union` is not allowed

Comment: And if you're not running Enterprise edition, be sure to use the NOEXPAND hint with any indexed views to gain the benefit.